# Should I stop charging my laptop battery at 50%?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I know that there are lots of questions about battery health and charging, but mine is very specific. For a lithium ion battery, leaving it at full charge (or low charge) damages the battery capacity. I am able on my laptop to stop the charging of the battery at a certain percentage between 50% and 100% in software. This is accomplished with dell's own software, power manager.

The question is therefore, would it be beneficial for my laptops battery capacity health to limit the charging to say 50%, when my laptop is plugged in for extended periods of time?

Comment: why not 80% or even 90%?

Comment: Because I was thinking to maximize the battery capacity longevity, and I was thinking 50% is more healthy than 80%

Comment: The proposed duplicate didn't answer the question I have: is it a good thing to keep it at 50%

Comment: You realize most Lithium-Ion packs have guard circuits that protect you from damaging the pack.  Further, many better manufacturers of equipment guard them **by giving you more battery than they say, and not letting you use it all**. E.g. In hurricanes, Tesla [grants access to the full range](https://arstechnica.com/cars/2018/10/tesla-remotely-extends-car-batteries-to-help-with-hurricane-michael/), or this very iPad, which got drained "50-90%" daily *for seven years* and still has a solid 6 hours range.  All that to say, **they may already do this for you**.

Comment: @Harper You are missing the point entirely. Yes I know this, the question is improved battery capacity by keeping it at around 50% when extended use of AC power.

Comment: @MariusGulbrandsen I see what you mean.  You totally captured it in that one sentence.   You meant *maintain the charge* at 50% state... Might be worth an edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would it be beneficial for my laptops battery capacity health to limit the charging to say 50%, when my laptop is plugged in for extended periods of time?

Yes it would, most manufacturers of Li-Ion based batteries charge them to a charge level of around 40% to have the lowest stress level in the battery and extend their storage lifetime. (Actually the batteries are not charged at the factory but assembled such that they have a 40% charge level, the balance of the chemicals is made such that this happens)

So 40% (50% is close enough) could indeed result in a longer lifetime of the battery **when you're not using it**. But as soon as you start using the battery, the charge level drops so the battery could end up having a much lower charge level for a while which causes more stress on the battery making it wear out more quickly.

In the end it will be a **compromise**, do you want to have the maximum battery charge available to you and accept that the battery will wear out sooner, or will you accept a smaller battery charge but have a battery that will wear out less quickly?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to take into account how much the battery will discharge when idle and/or in use.

For instance if you normally use 40% of battery charge during the day, and you want the day's average battery level to be 50%, then you might want to charge the battery up to 70%.  Your daily use will then typically drain it down to 30%, which isn't so low that it affects battery longevity.

Or if you store the device unused for long enough that the battery discharges 10%, then you might want to charge up to 55% (and let it discharge to 45%, averaging 50% over the storage time.)

Comment: I think it's safe to say the battery percentage would keep its charge for several days before this would be any issue?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answers

If you don't want to use the battery, 40% should be optimal. But if you want to use it, you have to develop a different strategy. If you find out, your battery is usually discharged by 40% when you are on the road or wherever you aren't connected to the grid. Then you could find a tradeof between

- losing power and ageing the battery by discharging it fully
- charging your battery higher and ageing it.

And if you keep your laptop e.g. 90% of the time connected to the grid the latter one should be the greater problem. Then you should choose a lower maximal charge.

If you are on the road all the time, it is more favourable to prevent the battery charge fall below a certain level most of the time.